# Mozart Function parse error

Tags: factorial, oz, mozart

when am trying to run this factorial function on this Mozart online 
[complier](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_mozart-oz_online.php)

i got parse error !

```
    declare
fun {Fact N}
   fun{Aux N Nmax FactNminus1}
      if N>Nmax then nil
      else (FactNminus1*N)|{Aux N+1 Nmax FactNminus1*N}
      end
   end
in
   {Aux 1 N 1}
end
{Browse {Fact 4}}
```

how i can run this piece of code on this online [compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_mozart-oz_online.php) !

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? Or a reference to a line?

Comment: i just got this piece of code from the internet and i just wanted to run it online, i can't merge this code to run correctly, when i write the function only it gives me syntax error at line 11, when i merge it with functor
 
import
   Application System   gives me parse error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is an Oz **script**. It can be used in the interactive Mozart IDE (Emacs).

The online compiler expects an Oz **program**, i.e. a functor definition. Try this code:

```
functor
import
   Application
   System
define
   fun {Fact N}
      fun{Aux N Nmax FactNminus1}
         if N > Nmax then nil
         else (FactNminus1*N)|{Aux N+1 Nmax FactNminus1*N}
         end
      end
   in
      {Aux 1 N 1}
   end

   {System.show {Fact 4}}
   {Application.exit 0}
end
```